# Design Tic Tac Toe Interview Problem [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, interview-questions, tic-tac-toe

Practicing objected oriented design. This time, it's designing the TicTacToe game. One difference between the real TicTacToe game is that I've made my TicTacToe game to have variable sized board.

Please review in terms of OOD and I've also left some comments in my code where I want feedback in particular. Thank you very much in advance.

Misc

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import Union, Optional, Callable


class InvalidInput(Exception):
    pass


class SpotTaken(Exception):
    def __init__(self, pos_x: int, pos_y: int) -> None:
        super().__init__(f'({pos_x}, {pos_y}) is already taken!')


class GameNotRunning(Exception):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__('Game is currently not running.')


class InvalidBoardSize(Exception):
    def __iter__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__('Board size must be a positive integer.')
```

TicTacToe

```
class TicTacToe:

    DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE = 3

    # Should this be inside the TicTacToe class or outside?
    class Turn(str, Enum):
        X = 'X'
        O = 'O'

        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return self.value

    # Should this be inside the TicTacToe class or outside?
    class State(Enum):
        RUNNING = 0
        TURN_WON = 1
        TIE = 2

    def __init__(self, board_size: Optional[int] = None) -> None:
        if board_size is not None and board_size <= 0:
            raise InvalidBoardSize()

        self.board_size = board_size or self.DEFAULT_BOARD_SIZE
        self.board: list[list[Union[None, str]]] = [[None] * self.board_size for _ in range(self.board_size)]
        self.turn = self.Turn.X
        self.state = self.State.RUNNING
        self.spots_left = self.board_size * self.board_size

    def do_turn(self, pos_x: int, pos_y: int) -> None:
        if self.state != self.State.RUNNING:
            raise GameNotRunning()

        if pos_x < 0 or pos_x >= self.board_size or pos_y < 0 or pos_y >= self.board_size:
            raise InvalidInput('pos_x or pos_y is out of bounds!')

        if self.board[pos_x][pos_y]:
            raise SpotTaken(pos_x=pos_x, pos_y=pos_y)

        self.board[pos_x][pos_y] = self.turn
        self.spots_left -= 1

        self._check_state()
        if self.state == self.State.RUNNING:
            self._change_turn()

    # Optimally, I don't have to check all 8 possible ways.
    # Technically, I only need to check the vertical of the column pos_y, the horizontal of the row pos_x,
    #   and the diagonals if the (pos_x, pos_y) overlaps with any of the points on the diagonal path.
    # However, just to have a simpler code, just do the check on all 8 ways always.
    # Since, these are such simple operations, it should not affect the performance really, anyway.
    def _check_state(self) -> None:
        # vertical check
        for row in range(self.board_size):
            winning_line_found = True
            for col in range(self.board_size):
                if self.board[row][col] != self.turn:
                    winning_line_found = False
                    break

            if winning_line_found:
                self.state = self.State.TURN_WON
                return

        # horizontal check
        for col in range(self.board_size):
            winning_line_found = True
            for row in range(self.board_size):
                if self.board[row][col] != self.turn:
                    winning_line_found = False
                    break

            if winning_line_found:
                self.state = self.State.TURN_WON
                return

        # top left to bottom right diagonal check
        winning_line_found = True
        for i in range(self.board_size):
            if self.board[i][i] != self.turn:
                winning_line_found = False
        if winning_line_found:
            self.state = self.State.TURN_WON
            return

        # top right to bottom left diagonal check
        winning_line_found = True
        for i in range(self.board_size):
            if self.board[i][self.board_size - i - 1] != self.turn:
                winning_line_found = False
        if winning_line_found:
            self.state = self.State.TURN_WON
            return

        if self.spots_left == 0:
            self.state = self.State.TIE

    def _change_turn(self) -> None:
        self.turn = self.Turn.X if self.turn == self.Turn.O else self.Turn.O

    def _get_status_msg(self) -> str:
        if self.state == self.State.RUNNING:
            msg = f'{self.turn}\'s turn.'
        elif self.state == self.State.TURN_WON:
            msg = f'{self.turn} WON!'
        else:
            msg = 'It\'s a TIE'

        return msg

    def _get_board_display(self) -> str:
        return '\n'.join(str([str(val) if val else ' ' for val in row]) for row in self.board)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (f'{self._get_board_display()}\n'
                f'{self._get_status_msg()}')
```

TicTacToe CLI Manager

```
class TicTacToeCLIManager:

    class State(Enum):
        DETERMINE_BOARD_SIZE = 0
        RUN_GAME = 1
        ASK_RESTART = 2
        QUIT = 3

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.tic_tac_toe: Union[TicTacToe, None] = None
        self.state = self.State.DETERMINE_BOARD_SIZE

    def run(self) -> None:
        while self.state != self.State.QUIT:
            self.STATE_TO_HANDLER[self.state](self)

    def _handle_determine_board_size_state(self) -> None:
        print('Determine the size of the board')
        board_size = None
        while board_size is None:
            user_input = input()
            try:
                board_size = int(user_input)
            except ValueError:
                print('The size of the board must be an integer')

        try:
            self.tic_tac_toe = TicTacToe(board_size=board_size)
        except InvalidBoardSize:
            print('The size of the board has to be a positive integer')
            return

        print(self.tic_tac_toe)
        self.state = self.State.RUN_GAME

    def _handle_run_game_state(self) -> None:
        user_input = input()
        user_input_split = user_input.split(' ')
        try:
            pos_x, pos_y = int(user_input_split[0]), int(user_input_split[1])
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            print('Inputs must have at least two integers separated by a space')
            print(self.tic_tac_toe)
            return

        try:
            self.tic_tac_toe.do_turn(pos_x=pos_x, pos_y=pos_y)
        except (InvalidInput, SpotTaken):
            print('Pick the position correctly, please')
        print(self.tic_tac_toe)

        if self.tic_tac_toe.state != self.tic_tac_toe.State.RUNNING:
            self.state = self.State.ASK_RESTART

    def _handle_ask_restart_state(self) -> None:
        print('Do you want to replay? If so, type y')
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == 'y':
            self.state = self.State.DETERMINE_BOARD_SIZE
        else:
            self.state = self.State.QUIT

    # I want to put this constant STATE_TO_HANDLER at the top of the class. I don't like constants being at the bottom.
    # However, if I put this above these methods, it cannot find the references to the methods.
    # What's the best practice regarding this?
    #
    # I wanted to put typing on the Callable's parameter and return types. Eg. Callable[[TicTacToeCLIManager], None]
    # However, the parameter type would be TicTacToeCLIManager and it cannot find the reference here
    #   since the TicTacToeCLIManager definition is not finished.
    # What's the best practice regarding this, too?
    STATE_TO_HANDLER: dict[State, Callable] = {
        State.DETERMINE_BOARD_SIZE: _handle_determine_board_size_state,
        State.RUN_GAME: _handle_run_game_state,
        State.ASK_RESTART: _handle_ask_restart_state,
    }
```

runner

```
def test():
    TicTacToeCLIManager().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an incomplete review up to the function `TicTacToe.turn`

---

Re: `if pos_x < 0 or pos_x >= self.board_size or pos_y < 0 or pos_y >= self.board_size:`

An alternative to `if x < min_x or x > max_x` is `if not min_x <= x <= max_x`. I think the latter is more readable, but that's up to opinion. In this case, if you wanted to make the change, you'd change `if pos_x < 0 or pos_x >= self.board_size` to `if not 0 <= pos_x < self.board_size` and likewise for `pos_y`.

---

Suggest you rename `self._check_state()` to `self._update_state()` or something that indicates that the function might modify `state`.

---

`# Optimally, I don't have to check all 8 possible ways.`

This comment is only valid for a board size of `3`. In general, an `N x N` board would have `2N + 2` possible "ways", so it might be beneficial to implement the optimization you mentioned. I.e. this optimization:

```
# Technically, I only need to check the vertical of the column pos_y, the horizontal of the row pos_x,
    #   and the diagonals if the (pos_x, pos_y) overlaps with any of the points on the diagonal path.
```

---

Horizontal check

```
        # vertical check
        for row in range(self.board_size):
            winning_line_found = True
            for col in range(self.board_size):
                if self.board[row][col] != self.turn:
                    winning_line_found = False
                    break
```

If you consider rows to be horizontal and columns to be vertical, then this is actually a `# horizontal check`

Second, the code can be simplified to

```
horiz_winning_line_found = any(row == [self.turn] * self.board_size for row in self.board)
```

or, better yet, if `y_pos` is passed into `self._check_state` as an argument, you can just do

```
horiz_winning_line_found = self.board[y_pos] == [self.turn] * self.board_size
```

If you decide to go with this, it would make sense to make `[self.Turn.X] * self.board_size` and `[self.Turn.O] * self.board_size` into [class variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056957/correct-way-to-define-class-variables-in-python) of the TicTocToe class.

---

This not the most OOP thing to do, but if you consider a different representation of `X` and `O` on the board where X is marked by `-1` and `O` is marked by `+1`, then the check state code could be simplified further. For example,

```
horiz_winning_line_found = self.board[y_pos] == [self.turn] * self.board_size
```

would become

```
horiz_winning_line_found = abs(sum(self.board[y_pos])) == self.board_size
```

also `self._change_turn` would simplify to

```
def _change_turn(self) -> None:
  self.turn *= -1
```

---

Vertical check

If you pass `x_pos` into `self._check_state`, then you can simplify the vertical winning line check to just

```
vert_winning_line_found = all(self.board[r][x_pos] == self.turn for r in range(self.board_size))
```

or

```
vert_winning_line_found = ''.join(self.board[r][x_pos] for r in range(self.board_size) == [self.turn] * self.board_size
```

---

You are mixing terms like (rows, columns) with (`x_pos`, `y_pos`). I would suggest you rename (`x_pos`, `y_pos`) to (`c`, `r`), (`col`, `row`), (`colNum`, `rowNum`) or something to that effect so that everything is in terms of rows and columns.

---

If you do end up passing `x_pos` and `y_pos` to `self._check_state`, here's a quick way to check whether `x_pos, y_pos` lie on the diagonal

```
# NW to SE diagonal
check_main_diag = x_pos == y_pos
```

```
# SW to NE diagonal
check_minor_diag = x_pos == self.board_size - 1 - y_pos
```

then you can just do

```
main_diag_winning_line = check_main_diag * all(self.board[i][i] == self.turn for i in range(self.board_size))
```

and something similar for `minor_diag_winning_line`

Comment: Awesome ways to check the result! Thank you very much.